# Laravel Backpack Error 500 Please pass setValidation() nothing, a rules array or a FormRequest class

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've used Backpack for Laravel to generate a super-simple admin dashboard on my local app dev computer. Now I'm using Git to push it to a remote "hub" server (my own, not GitHub) and then pulling it into a remote "beta" server for testing.

Everything seems fine ... I can navigate among the several CRUDs I've generated, the data appears OK, etc.

BUT when I click an Edit link or click the `+ Add <entity>` button I get

```
ERROR
500
It's not you, it's me.
Please pass setValidation() nothing, a rules array or a FormRequest class.
```

The App Dev and the Beta codebase should be identical, thanks to Git. But obviously some difference has crept in somewhere. Does that error message suggest to anyone where the difference might be?

Details:

```
PHP 7.4.33 on Beta, 7.4.19 on App Dev
LARAVEL v8.83.27 on both
backpack/crud: 5.5.1 on both
backpack/generators: 3.3.16 on both
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of your `CrudController` is trying to send an invalid argument to `CRUD::setValidation(...)` method.
As the error states, `setValidation` allows *"a rules array or a FormRequest class"*.

Usually, I opt for the FormRequest class, and it goes like `CRUD::setValidation(EntityRequest::class)`. Also note that you're probably using this method twice in your controllers, in `setupCreateOperation` and `setupUpdateOperation`.

```php
public function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(EntityRequest::class);
}

public function setupUpdateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(EntityRequest::class);
}
```

You may also send a rules array, as the [docs point out](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-create#b-validating-fields-using-a-rules-array);

```php
CRUD::setValidation([
    'name' => 'required|min:2',
    // ...
]);
```

Please check wherever you're using `setValidation` because at least one of it is wrong.

---

Side note, if you are starting a new project, I highly recommend you to use the latest PHP *(8.2, or at least 8.1)* and latest Laravel *(10)*. Backpack supports both.

Comment: Thanks! I investigated further and found that a) I'm using `CRUD::setValidation(EntityRequest::class)` in every controller, and b) Git did not `pull` the `request` folder from the hub! So this is apparently a Git problem, not a Backpack problem. I'll investigate further and open a new question re: Git if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you may need to check your `App/Http/Requests` folder.
Instead of `[Model]Request.php` you may have `Store[Model]Request.php` and `Update[Model]Request.php` created separately, and because of that `CRUD::setValidation([Model]Request::class)` wont work.

update like this worked for me:

```
CRUD::setValidation(**Update**EntityRequest::class);
```